# Error in parsing nested JSON list in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Calling API but showing error, I'm unable to parse data in the bean class.

My Response:

```
   {
"error":"0",
"status":200,
"deliveryCharge":"14.00",
"image_base_url":"http:\/\/xxxxx.tk\/assets\/event\/image\/",
"image_logo_url":"http:\/\/xxxxx.tk\/assets\/event\/logo\/",
"eventList":[
{
"event_id":"1",
"event_name":"Syscraft Premier League",
"event_location":"12 ny valleys",
"event_type_id":"15",
"start_date":"2019-01-10 03:21:00",
"end_date":"2019-01-26 16:10:00",
"event_logo":"f4f0bfc168a3816891e2749232c5243f.jpg"
},
{
"event_id":"3",
"event_name":"Republic Day Event 2019",
"event_location":"AH-654 Villa No. 42 New Township New Township",
"event_type_id":"1",
"start_date":"2019-01-26 00:00:00",
"end_date":"2019-01-26 11:55:00",
"event_logo":"3a4a7fabbbd7ed8febf67bacda71ae48.jpg"
}
]
}
```

Calling Api

```
  Future<List<EventResponse>> fetchEvent( ) async {

String url='http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.tk/api/userapp/event/lists';
var headers = new Map();
headers['Auth-Key'] = 'OCDOC@2018';
headers['End-Client'] = 'OCDOC';
var body = new Map();
headers['schedule'] = 'present';
http.Response res = await http.post(url,headers: headers, body: body);
final Map<String,dynamic> parsed=json.decode(res.body); // post api call
print("Reposnce Event:---"+parsed.toString());}
```

My Bean class

```
class EventResponse{


String error;
  int status;
  String deliveryCharges;
  String imageBaseUrl;
  String imageLogoUrl;
  List<Event> eventList;

  EventResponse({
             this.error,
             this.status,
             this.deliveryCharges,
             this.imageBaseUrl,
             this.imageLogoUrl,
             this.eventList
               });

  factory EventResponse.convertEventResponse(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return EventResponse(
                            error: json['error'],
                            status:  json['status'],
                            deliveryCharges:  json['deliveryCharge'],
                            imageBaseUrl:  json['image_base_url'],
                            imageLogoUrl:  json['image_logo_url'],
                            eventList:  json['eventList']);

  }}
class Event{

  String eventId;
  String eventName;
  String location;
  String event_logo;

  Event({
    this.eventId,
    this.eventName,
    this.location,
    this.event_logo,
  });

  factory Event.convertEvent(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return Event(
      eventId: json['event_id'],
      eventName:  json['event_name'],
      location:  json['event_location'],
      event_logo:  json['event_logo'],

    );}}
```

Showing Error

> `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, String>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed `EventResponse` as @Richard Heap did.

```
factory EventResponse.convertEventResponse(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
List<dynamic> events = json['eventList'];
List<Event> eventList = events.map((e) => Event.convertEvent(e)).toList();
return EventResponse(
    error: json['error'],
    status: json['status'],
    deliveryCharges: json['deliveryCharge'],
    imageBaseUrl: json['image_base_url'],
    imageLogoUrl: json['image_logo_url'],
    eventList: eventList,
    );
  }
}
```

One more thing I need to change is when I post `parameters` and `headers` need to define their `Map()` to `Map<String,String>()`.

```
 Future<EventResponse> fetchEvent( ) async { // here i change Future type

String url='http://xxxxxxx-oceanapparel.tk/api/userapp/event/lists';
var headers = new Map<String, String>(); //here i defined Map type
headers['Auth-Key'] = 'OCDOC@2018';
headers['End-Client'] = 'OCDOC';
var body = new Map<String, String>(); //here i defined Map type
headers['schedule'] = 'present';
http.Response res = await http.post(url,headers: headers, body: body);

print("Reposnce Event:---"+res.body);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite `EventResponse` like this:

```
class EventResponse {
  String error;
  int status;
  String deliveryCharges;
  String imageBaseUrl;
  String imageLogoUrl;
  List<Event> eventList;

  EventResponse(
      {this.error,
      this.status,
      this.deliveryCharges,
      this.imageBaseUrl,
      this.imageLogoUrl,
      this.eventList});

  factory EventResponse.convertEventResponse(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<dynamic> events = json['eventList'];
    List<Event> eventList = events.map((e) => Event.convertEvent(e)).toList();
    return EventResponse(
        error: json['error'],
        status: json['status'],
        deliveryCharges: json['deliveryCharge'],
        imageBaseUrl: json['image_base_url'],
        imageLogoUrl: json['image_logo_url'],
        eventList: eventList,
        );
  }
}
```