# Flutter: InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments

Tags: android, api, http, dart, flutter

I'm unable to find solutions from the previously available question, I have cast  `json` string to `map`

Below is my API calling method.

```
Future<EventResponse> fetchEvent( ) async { // here i change Future type

 String url='http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.tk/api/userapp/event/lists';

 var headers = new Map<String, String>();//here i defined Map type
 headers['Auth-Key'] = 'OCDOC@2018';
 headers['End-Client'] = 'OCDOC';

 var body = new Map<String, String>();//here i defined Map type
 headers['schedule'] = 'present';

 http.Response res = await http.post(url,headers: headers, body: body);

 final parsed=json.decode(res.body);
 var myMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(parsed);
 EventResponse eventResponse = EventResponse.convertEventResponse(myMap);
 return eventResponse;


 }
```

this is my `convertEventResponse` methode

```
factory EventResponse.convertEventResponse(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<dynamic> events = json['eventList'];
    List<Event> eventList = events.map((e) => Event.convertEvent(e)).toList(); //here i changed by @Richard Heap answer
    return EventResponse(
      error: json['error'],
      status: json['status'],
      deliveryCharges: json['deliveryCharge'],
      imageBaseUrl: json['image_base_url'],
      imageLogoUrl: json['image_logo_url'],
      eventList: eventList,
    );
  }
```

The error i'm getting.

> ```
> InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.
> ```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use instead

```
.cast<String,dynamic>();
```

See also https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Map/cast.html

Usually it's better to use `Map<String,String>.from(oldMap)` instead of `cast<...>(...)`

Comment: see my updated code, now showing error `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`, if you want to see reponse (class)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328517/error-in-parsing-nested-json-list-in-flutter/54329891#54329891]

Comment: I don't see `myMap['error']` in your code. The error message means that you have a target of type `String` and you try to pass a `List<dynamic>` to it.

Comment: There is not enough information. The code you mentioned in the comment is not in your question. Perhaps it's `error: json['error'],` where `error` is `String´ and `json['error']` returns a `List<dynamic>` but there is no information what `error´ is.

Comment: see this link you can find the bean class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328517/error-in-parsing-nested-json-list-in-flutter/54329891#54329891]).

Comment: Which says `String error;` but I still can't know what `json['error']` returns.

Comment: `json`  is a map object

Comment: But the question was what `json['error']` returns. A `Map<String,dynamic>` can contain anything

Comment: Okay i got your point, `Map<String,dynamic>` it should be like `Map<dynamic,dynamic>` becuase we can not know what type of key is.

Comment: No, that's not the point. The type of the key is always `String` in JSON, but we can't know what type the value is because it can be `int`, `double`, `bool`, `String`, `List<...>`, `Map<String, ...` where `...` is any of the listed types.

Comment: Somewhere i was getting an error like `InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>'  to `map<String,dynamic>` now  i remove `map` type from convert methode argument and rest of the things are same as you told....now it is working.

Comment: tried this approach still data not loaded in list.

Comment: can we send query parameter with post api  in flutter?